# Buying an iPad through an iTunes account?

Tags: itunes, mac-appstore

Is it possible to use the iTunes account to buy an iPad?

I'd like to build up credit using iTunes prepaid cards with 20% credit to buy a new iPad Mini Retina. I think there is no restriction to what you buy through the store.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumption is wrong. You can only buy Apps from the iTunes Store, App Store, iBooks Store, and Mac App Store.

```
All cards work on the iTunes Store, App Store, iBooks Store, and Mac App Store. 
Select the gift card that's perfect for your lucky recipient.
You can include a personal message, and you always get free shipping.
```

[Source](http://store.apple.com/us/personalize/itunes)